# How to add file extension in postgresql

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-migration

I'm Migrating oracle database to postgres while migrating i'm facing some issue in UTL_FILE Extension and DBMS_Extension. Please help me in adding extensions in postgresql in centos7.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sc_04.pf0s0032(
    p_data_id       IN  VARCHAR,   -- データID
    p_transact_no   OUT BIGINT,     -- トランザクションNo.
    p_rtncode       OUT BIGINT,     -- リターンコード
    p_status        OUT BIGINT,     -- リターンコード
    p_SQLSTATE       OUT BIGINT,     -- SQLコード
    p_sqlerrm       OUT VARCHAR    -- SQLエラーメッセージ
) RETURNS RECORD AS $$

  DECLARE 

            -- PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

    w_site_id       m_data_id.site_id%TYPE;            
    w_server_id     m_data_id.server_id%TYPE;           
    w_transact_no   BIGINT;
    w_file_name     t_ymate_send_ctl.file_name%TYPE;   
    w_file_dir      t_ymate_send_ctl.file_dir%TYPE;     
    w_upd_date      TIMESTAMP(0);                               
    w_upd_person    VARCHAR(6);                       
    w_log_status    BIGINT;
    w_log_SQLSTATE   BIGINT;
    w_log_sqlerrm   VARCHAR(1000);
 w_file_handle   UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;                 




    w_file_name     := p_data_id || TO_CHAR(w_transact_no, 'FM00000000') || '.txt';
    w_file_dir      := sc_00.SEND_IF_DIR;
    w_file_handle   := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(w_file_dir, w_file_name, 'w');
    w_file_handle           := UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(w_file_handle);
                            SELECT sc_02.pf0s0007( 'SC',                     '0s0032',
                                                                                            '1.3 送信ファイル名作成',
                                                                                            0,
                                                                                            'w_file_name:' || w_file_name || ',w_file_dir:' || w_file_dir);
                            SELECT sc_02.pf0s0007( 'SC',
                                                                                            '0s0032',
                                                                                            '1.4 送信管理テーブル登録',
                                                                                            0,
                                                                                            'site_id:' || w_site_id || ',server_id:' || w_server_id);
```

Comment: Please show the original code and whatever you have tried in Postgres. You should also show us som sample data and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please see the updated description

Comment: You can use the orafce extension, but essentially you'll have to rewrite your function.